# Can I say “a man happy in the library”?

Tags: prepositions

Can I say “a man happy in the library”? It means “a man who is happy when he is in the library.”

Comment: You can play with words in informal language. But the sentence is not correct in formal writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say that - omitting pronouns and prepositions is allowed as long as you can still understand the sentence; in this case, you can. However, is this the **effect** you want: literary, wistful, poetic, dreamlike? It sounds like it is from an older time, and some may think it old-fashioned.